# Strange behavior of round() when 5 is the digit to round

Tags: python, rounding

When 5 is the last digit, the round() function doesn't always round up. Instead, it alternates between rounding up and rounding down.

Example:

```
print(round(1.5))
>>>2
print(round(2.5))
>>>2
```

Could anyone explain **why this happens** and **how to always round up in this situation**?

Comment: That is the intended behavior. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round): _"if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice"_

Comment: If one of the answers meets your needs, please extend the courtesy of accepting the answer.

Comment: @Carl_M The courtesy's sure been extended ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possible work-around for the round function's behaviour.

```
import math

some_value = 35

print(math.ceil(someValue / 10) * 10 if some_value % 5 == 0  else round(some_value, -1))
```

This code checks if the value is divisible by 5, and if it is, it divides the value by 10, rounds UP the value (`ceil`), and again multiplies it by 10 - otherwise executes the simple old round function :)

You could wrap that in a function as well :-

```
def round_val(val):
  return math.ceil(val / 10) * 10 if val % 5 == 0 else round(val, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice.
# The decision to round towards even makes subsequent calculations more accurate.
z = float(15)
print(round(z, -1))  # 20 because the 10's digit 1 is odd 2 is the next even
# digit
y = float(25)  # 20 because the 10's digit 2 is even
print(round(y, -1))
# Assume rounding up always. Using the example numbers 15 and 25 rounding
# down would be 20 and 30.
print(f'Sum of rounding up={sum((20, 30))}')
print(f'Sum of actual numbers={sum((15, 25))}')
print(f'Sum of rounding toward even={sum((z, y))}')
print(f'Average of rounding up={sum((20, 30)) / 2}')
print(f'Average of actual numbers={sum((15, 25)) / 2}')
print(f'Average of rounding toward even={sum((z, y)) / 2}')


# If rounding up is desired it can be accomplished with a function:
def round_up_fives(number):
    if not number // 5:  # number is not evenly divisible by 5
        return round(number, -1)
    else:
        return number + 5


print(f'{round_up_fives(z)=}')
print(f'{round_up_fives(y)=}')
```

Output

```
20.0
20.0
Sum of rounding up=50
Sum of actual numbers=40
Sum of rounding toward even=40.0
Average of rounding up=25.0
Average of actual numbers=20.0
Average of rounding toward even=20.0
round_up_fives(z)=20.0
round_up_fives(y)=30.0
```